# Dart/Flutter ffi (Foreign Function Interface) native callbacks eg: sqlite3_exec

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

Hello I am using dart:ffi to build an interface with my native c/c++ library.
and I needed a way to get a callback from c to dart as an example in sqlite:

```
int sqlite3_exec(
    sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
    const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
    int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
    void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
    char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

the third parameter in `sqlite3_exec` is function pointer to a callback.
so if I called this function in dart using `ffi` I need to pass a function pointer: and in `dart:ffi` `Pointer` class there is a function named `fromFunction` witch accepts a dart static function and an `exceptionalReturn`; but just by calling this function to get the function pointer of a dart managed function: a `(sigterm)` is raised and the dart code no long work in the process.

So My Question: Is there any way to get a native callback in dart, as in Python, c#, ..

Extra:
Is there any way to include `dartino` in a `flutter` project, since this [ForeignDartFunction](https://dartino.github.io/api/dart-dartino.ffi/ForeignDartFunction/ForeignDartFunction.html) covers what I need.

Comment: Have you looked at `Pointer.fromFunction`? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-ffi/Pointer/fromFunction.html

Comment: @julemand101 Yes I did, it is implied by my question, the documentation has no example for `fromFunction`.

Comment: Ah sorry, did not read that part.

Comment: Are you sure that the callback is being made on the main thread, and not one created in the library.

Comment: @RichardHeap I did not get to call the function, just getting the callback function pointer in dart raised ‘sigterm’ when called ‘Pointer.fromFunction’

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I got an example to work. Hopefully you can adapt this to your case.

**Example C function**

```
EXTERNC int32_t foo(
                    int32_t bar,
                    int32_t (*callback)(void*, int32_t)
                    ) {
    return callback(nullptr, bar);
}
```

**Dart code**

First the `typedefs`. We need two for the native function `foo` and one for the Dart callback.

```
typedef example_foo = Int32 Function(
    Int32 bar, Pointer<NativeFunction<example_callback>>);
typedef ExampleFoo = int Function(
    int bar, Pointer<NativeFunction<example_callback>>);

typedef example_callback = Int32 Function(Pointer<Void>, Int32);
```

and the code for the callback

```
  static int callback(Pointer<Void> ptr, int i) {
    print('in callback i=$i');
    return i + 1;
  }
```

and the lookup

```
  ExampleFoo nativeFoo =
    nativeLib.lookup<NativeFunction<example_foo>>('foo').asFunction();
```

and, finally, use it like this:

```
  int foo(int i) {
    return nativeFoo(
      i,
      Pointer.fromFunction<example_callback>(callback, except),
    );
  }
```

as expected, `foo(123)` prints `flutter: in callback i=123` and returns `124`

Comment: thank you, I already had a working example,I will mark this as a correct answer since it covers every thing needed.

Comment: Yes, I should have shown that too. `static const except = -1;`

Comment: my issue was with the 2nd parameter  `exceptionalReturn ` in `fromFunction`, dart requires it to be a constant value, and apparently -5 (and negative value) is not a constant value for the dart compiler /interpreter.
So I need to ask you did it work correctly having the value stored in a variable named `except`.

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work for a Dart created thread, so sync calls, async callbacks, ie. if theSqlite does the callback on a thread Sqlite created will **NOT** work as its breaks Darts threading-concurrency safety model, which is tracked in: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37022.

Comment: @RichardHeap If so, is it possible to receive 124, the retrun value of dart, when calling foo from `main` in C?

Comment: No - as in the comment above, you can only call from C to Dart if that C function is itself being called from Dart.